# XCTest for when iCloud is enabled and disabled

Tags: swift, unit-testing, icloud, cloudkit, xctest

I have a viewMode that determines if iCloud is enabled or disabled with the result being a prompt to the User to login to iCloud or not.

Is there a way to progamatically login/logout to iCloud from an XCTest to reliable test all paths?

Here is my test

```
func testShowLoginButtonForiCloud() {
  let viewModel = OnboardingViewModel()
  let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Wait for CKContainer auth check")
  var iCloudEnabled: Bool?

  viewModel.shouldShowiCloudLogin { result, error in
    iCloudEnabled = result
    expectation.fulfill()
  }
  wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 5.0)

  XCTAssertNotNil(iCloudEnabled)
  XCTAssertFalse(iCloudEnabled!)
}
```

Here is my ViewModel

```
typealias Completion = (Bool, Error?) -> Void

final class OnboardingViewModel {
  func shouldShowiCloudLogin(completion: @escaping Completion) {
  CKContainer.default().accountStatus { (status, error) in
    switch status {
      case .available :
        completion(true, nil)
       default :
        completion(false, error)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a detail, but I want to play with the code: Could you add the definition of `Completion`? And did you mean to have it `@escaping`?

Comment: Made it because I thought I need local variables to preserve.

Comment: I updated the comment to include the typealias. It's a function that takes a bool and an optional Error.

Answer (score 1):

Can we programmatically log in to CloudKit for unit testing? This is inadvisable, because even if we could, the tests would be slow & fragile. Instead, treat CloudKit as an architectural boundary. Unit tests can go right up to this boundary. And we can pretend stuff comes back from the boundary. In this way, we can test all paths.

To program this boundary into your code, use a protocol. This protocol will be a slice containing only those CKContainer methods you want. (This is the Interface Segregation Principle in action.) Since CKContainer already implements this method, we can attach it as an empty extension.

```
protocol CKContainerProtocol {
    func accountStatus(completionHandler: @escaping (CKAccountStatus, Error?) -> Void)
}

extension CKContainer: CKContainerProtocol {}
```

Then add a property to your view model:

```
var cloudKitContainer: CKContainerProtocol = CKContainer.default()
```

The default value means your code will continue to use the real CKContainer unless told otherwise. Change your code to call `cloudKitContainer` instead of `CKContainer.default()`.

Then in test code, you can provide a different implementation of CKContainerProtocol. This will let you do stubbing and mocking. You can confirm that `accountStatus()` is called exactly once. And you can exercise its closure with different CKAccountStatus values to confirm how your Completion closure is called.